# How can I check if my laptop's wireless card supports 802.11AC wifi?

Tags: wireless, 16.10

I tried some commands like `iw list` and `iwconfig` but couldn't see the supported wifi version (b/g/n/ac).

Comment: Try something from http://superuser.com/q/679723/334516, maybe.

Comment: Why did you downvote me? What did I do wrong?

Comment: O.o Why do you think I did?

Comment: Well, that was  a general question to whoever did.

Comment: The only person who got notified was me. Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: Sorry, I just really cant understand ranking sometimes. If i did something wrong, please tell me so I can improve.

Comment: @KobiT  the stackoverflow network in and of itself is like that - people can downvote  but are not required to provide info why.  As for your question, I'd say simplest way is to find out the model of the card, and google it's capabilities

Comment: Well, for desktop maybe. But as stated, its a laptop with integrated one so I assumed that there's a terminal command that shows this info, just couldnt find it after a short search on google.

Comment: What wireless card do you have?

Comment: Built in in xps 13 9343

Comment: @KobiT Your message of "See title.  This message is too sort." suggests you have not done any research on your own part first.  That might explain the down votes.  If you have done some Googling or whatever, tell us...help us to help you.

Comment: Fair enough. I tried some commands I saw like `iw list` and `iwconfig` but couldn't see the supported wifi version (b/g/n/ac).

Comment: @KobiT  you can find it via `lshw -c network` command, regardless of whether it's a laptop or desktop

Comment: It shows: `... product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter ...` So I guess it's all good. Thank you mate.

Comment: @KobiT in your case it's lucky coincidence. if that was different card, you'd still have to google the card and it's capabilities. I'll post answer with my own example in a minute

Comment: Yea, I figured they added the AC to the name of the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to find out your card type and search online its capabilities.  The command to find your hardware is `lshw -c network`. In my case, this gives:

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan7
       version: 01
       serial: d0:53:49:3d:53:fd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.78 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:d0700000-d077ffff memory:d0780000-d078ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Note, that in your case as shown in comments for your card it's just a lucky coincidence that the card product description shows `product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter`  In my example description shows model only.

Comment: If the product description shows that, it might also show up in `lspci`, which is usually faster than `lshw`.

Comment: @muru that can be done , too, I just prefer `lshw` because `-c` option allows filtering out specifically what you want. And speed . . . meh, it's not like it needs to be instant, user can wait a few seconds